# SQL Incorrect integer value

Tags: sql, integer

I am trying to resolve the following error as listed below. I have done a var_dump to ensure the value (int(15)) is as expect A: An int; B: not empty/null; C: correct expected value. My tests have failed to resolve the issue, only identify it as I understand it to persist.

I am hoping someone can further explain the issue to me and provide guidance so that I can resolve what I thought was a simple error, but I am unable to resolve this error. I have tried for most of the night to resolve this error. I have searched StackOverflow, CodeAcademy, Googled, etc. I have not found an answer that can help me to resolve this error. Thank you for your help.

**Problem:** insert statement fails

**Issue identified:** first int given (`$threadID`) - expected value for int(15) is '15'

**var_dump:** int(15) #correct

**Error (short)**

> General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'pt_threadID' for column 'pt_threadID' at row 1

**Error (full)**

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'pt_threadID' for column 'pt_threadID' at row 1 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MCUv22/is_forum/process.php:1196 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MCUv22/is_forum/process.php(1196): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MCUv22/is_forum/process.php(422): replyADD(Object(PDO), 15, 35, 0, 0, 21, 78, 0, '', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'I"m an example test...', 'test copy is ...', 'shitty of bosto...', 0, 0, 'finished', 'scene', 'open', 'loose', 'moderate', 'ic', 0, 1, 1, 'NYC', 'a landmark', '', 'Castle Rock, Mn...', 'address is opti...', 'afternoon', -65, 'flood', '3 | 3 | 3', 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, '', NULL, NULL, 'a:2:{i:0;s:6:"m...', 'a:2:{i:0;s:11:"...', 'X, Bobby Belche...', '', 99, '2013-12-18', '2013-12-18', '15:06:38', '15:06:38') #2 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/MCUv22/is_forum/process.php on line 1196

Code:

```
var_dump($threadID)  ==  int(15)# correct expected value

#build string for SQL insert with replacement vars, ?
$sql = " 
INSERT INTO `frm_POST`
(
`pt_threadID`
 )VALUES(
:pt_threadID
)
;";

# $statement->bindValue(':threadID', "$threadID");
# addition bind values removed for brevity to focus on issue
# tested statement as given above, same error persists
# Prepare our statement using the SQL query.
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);

$statement->bindValue(':pt_threadID', "pt_threadID");

//Execute the statement and insert our values.
$inserted = $statement->execute();
//clear - free up connection
unset($statement, $db);//clear
```

Comment: On this line `statement->bindValue(':pt_threadID', "pt_threadID");` shouldn't the second argument be a variable rather than a string?  In other words shouldn't `"pt_threadID"` actually be `$pt_threadID`?

Comment: I revised the test statement, changing "pt_threadID" to $threadID and it has worked

Comment: Is there a way to accept your comment @Steven Rumbalski as the answer so you get the points?